# PHP Generating unique div ID

Tags: php, html, css

i am trying to generate unique div ID using php but i don't know how do i make that on style also. cause as you see here my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style>
#<?php echo generateRandomString(); ?> {background:#000;color:#fff;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
?>

<div id="<?php echo generateRandomString(); ?>">Hello World</div>

</body>
</html>
```

every time you refresh the page it will give you unique id but it doesn't give both id and on style same id that's how i can't style the id

Comment: Generate the id at the top of the page, save it in a variable, and echo the variable wherever you need it

Comment: @EatPeanutButter still different ID

Comment: MmPp: What @EatPeanutButter meant is to generate the id _once_, save it to a var and use it twice. like `$unique = generateRamdomString();`

Comment: @EatPeanutButter can you show me on answer how to do it?

Comment: @Jeff can you answer question and show m clearly how ?

Comment: .@AkshayHegde made an aswer that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

```
$unique_id = 'mydiv_'.uniqid();
```

You have to do like below, everytime when you make call to `generateRandomString()` id will change so, in the beginning you have to save it in variable, and then just `echo` wherever it is required.

```
<?php 
       $unique_id = 'mydiv_'.uniqid(); // generate

       // OR your 

       // $unique_id = generateRandomString();
?>
<style>
#<?php echo $unique_id; ?> {background:#000;color:#fff;}
</style>
<div id="<?php echo $unique_id; ?>">Hello World</div>
```